# python and ngrok with options gives me an error

Tags: python, ngrok, pyngrok

I am trying to run `ngrok` with `options` I tried

```
from pyngrok import ngrok
ngrokPublicUrl = ngrok.connect(5000, bind_tls= True)
```

and

```
ngrokPublicUrl = ngrok.connect(remote_addr=5000, bind_tls= True)
```

For options I used the documentation here --> https://ngrok.com/docs#tunnel-definitions.   I am trying to get the https address not http. It looks like `options` usage is not correct?

but I get this error

```
TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'remote_addr'
```

or

```
TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind_tls'
```

Comment: From the pyngrok documentation: "The connect() method can also take an options parameter, which allows us to pass additional options that are supported by ngrok."  So something like `ngrok.connect(options={'remote_addr': 5000, 'bind_tls': True})` I think

Comment: Thx I am looking for python usage tried already --> ngrok.connect('remote_addr':5000)  or ngrok.connect('remote_addr'=5000)  the trouble is usage how do I use it with python or the syntax

Answer (score 0):

### Update

With `pyngrok>=5`, `options` have been unpacked to `kwargs`, meaning the question asker's original syntax will now work just fine, though it should also be noted with this update that `connect()` now returns a [`NgrokTunnel`](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/5.0.0/api.html#pyngrok.ngrok.NgrokTunnel) instead of the `public_url` as a `str` like it used to.

### Original Answer (for `pyngrok<=4.1`)

I am the developer of `pyngrok`. The correct Python snippet was given in the comment above, I'll post it here as well so it can be marked as an answered.

You cannot pass this parameter directly to the `connect()`, as you are trying to do, you need to pass it as an `options` dictionary to connect() (which will be unpacked to the tunnel definitions in the documentation you've linked—see the API docs [here](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.16/api.html#pyngrok.ngrok.connect)).

```
from pyngrok import ngrok

options = {
   "remote_addr": 5000,
   "bind_tls": True
}
ngrokPublicUrl = ngrok.connect(options=options)
```

Perhaps `options` would more intuitively be unpacked in `connect()` as `kwargs`? I'll take note of that to consider as a future improvement, but for now you need to do it the way described above.